# JQuery ()load in a specific page?id=# number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chat

I have the following problem: I need to have multiple private chatrooms per user.
I managed it to make it work but if there is more than one private chat ongoing on the same moment, the appended content of these chats are broadcasted to all private chatrooms.

```
function RefreshPrivate(userid)
    {
         var string_url = "./functions/ShowMessagePrivate.php?id=" + userid;
         var page_url = "private.php?id=" + userid ;
        $("#chatPrivateBody").append($("<div>").load(string_url));

    }
```

The problem happens because of the `$("#chatPrivateBody")`,every **private.php** has that `<div>`, what I was thinking was that if I can append the string_url to page_url specific `<div>`

e.g  `$(page_url,"#chatPrivateBody")` but there's nothing for this in the documantation of jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention "every private.php". So I assume you have multiple instances of this page loaded up on the same page at the same time, which either means that each one is loaded into some container via AJAX, or each one is in an iframe. You haven't really specified what you do with `page_url`.

I assume you're loading the pages via AJAX. If that's the case, each private chatroom gets loaded into a separate container (probably a `<div>`).

And each container will probably have a unique id (probably something like `chatroom-<userid>`).

If this is true, then you can target the `#chatPrivateBody` within the specific chatroom you're looking for:

```
$('#chatroom-'+ userid)
    .find('#chatPrivateBody')
    .append($("<div>").load(string_url));
```

Comment: oh thanks!, i am new here so i didn't knew about this